# Unexpected token '??=' when running node server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\food\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bson.js:4:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

I converted the server code to ES6 format thinking maybe that might solve it but didn't really help

I see this inside the bson.js node module file:

inspect ??= defaultInspect;

this is my server.js:

```
import http from 'http';
import { teams } from './db/conn.js';
http
.createServer(async (req, res) => {
    // THIS IS FOR CORS ERRORS
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        '*'
    ); /* @dev First, read about security */
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 2592000); // 30 days
    if (req.url == '/api/food') {
        try {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            const dataset = await food(); // here we get the string json
            res.write(dataset); // whoever requests will get the string json as response
        } finally {
            res.end(); // must end response
        }
    }
})
.listen(4000);
```

**conn.js:**

```
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(uri);
export async function foods() {
try {
    const dataset = await client.db('restaurant').collection('foods').find().toArray();
    return JSON.stringify(dataset);
} catch {
    console.log('db closed');
    await client.close();
}
}
```